# T-SQL Left Outer Join Select Top 1 - MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data from a table that looks like this:

```
encounter | prov_id_name
---------------------------
12345678  | 123456ProviderA
```

I then want to match it up on the provider id from a dimensional table instead of pulling in the substring if there is a match in the dim table.

The dimensional table looks like the following:

```
orgz_cd | src_pract_no | pract_rpt_name
----------------------------------------
0002    | 123456       | PROVIDER A X
1234    | 123456       | Provider A
4321    | 123456       | Provider A
```

I used the following SQL worked to get what I needed:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ZZZ.src_pract_no
    , MAX(ZZZ.pract_rpt_name) PRACT_RPT_NAME
    FROM smsdss.pract_dim_v AS ZZZ
    GROUP BY src_pract_no
) AS MD
ON LEFT(HL7.PRIM_CARE_PROV_NAME_ID, 6) = MD.SRC_PRACT_NO
```

My question is why did this not work, which is what I originally tried, which would give no results at all:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT TOP 1 ZZZ.src_pract_no
    , MAX(ZZZ.pract_rpt_name) PRACT_RPT_NAME
    FROM smsdss.pract_dim_v AS ZZZ
) AS MD
ON LEFT(HL7.PRIM_CARE_PROV_NAME_ID, 6) = MD.SRC_PRACT_NO
```

I also tried:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN smsdss.pract_dim_v AS MD
ON LEFT(HL7.PRIM_CARE_PROV_NAME_ID, 6) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 SRC_PRACT_NO
    , PRACT_RPT_NAME
    FROM SMSDSS.PRACT_DIM_V
)
```

I am thinking no results came back or rather it did not work as I expected because the subquery is being evaluated only once for the first result that comes back not finding a match and then that's it, not sure though.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the subquery would only be executed once and there is no guarantee that it would match the ID that you are looking for in your ON condition.

Comment: 1. `TOP(n)` doesn't make much sense without an `ORDER BY`. It just picks an arbitrary record from the matches. 2. `SELECT TOP 1 ZZZ.src_pract_no, MAX(ZZZ.pract_rpt_name)` is invalid without a `GROUP BY ZZZ.src_pract_no`. 3. The original subquery selects one row *per src_pract_no*, your alternative selects one row only.

Comment: Thank you both, so I was on the right track of thinking, just missing a few key points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `OUTER APPLY`:

```
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 pd.pract_rpt_name
 FROM smsdss.pract_dim_v pd
 WHERE LEFT(HL7.PRIM_CARE_PROV_NAME_ID, 6) = pd.SRC_PRACT_NO
 -- ORDER BY ?
) MD
```

Use an `ORDER BY` if you want a particular name (such as the longest or most recent) when there are multiple matches.